# window.onclick function not removing class if div contains certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css

nothing happens when I click anywhere in the screen, it won't remove the class show... I have looked into some other post, but those didn't work for me as well

```js
function dropdownmenu() {
  document.getElementById("settingsPanel").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("og-settings").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content menu-panel");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dropdownmenu()" class="dropbtn">
</button>

<div id="settingsPanel" class="dropdown-content">
  <div id="og-settings" class="menu-panel" style="background-color: #e8a0a0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like `!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')` would always be passed ..?

Comment: @Teemu sorry, but what do you mean by would always be passed?

Comment: Because there's no element with the class `dropbtn` in your example.

Comment: @Teemu oh sorry, I've edited my post with another button

Comment: @Daniel makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

if You have more then one class, can't do it with getElementsByClassName() method instead use querySelectorAll() method with comma separated class selectors.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content .menu-panel')
```

Comment: tried that, but it only remove show class from one class